# How does c++ initialize an object? Is the following case doing that twice?

Tags: c++, constructor

Suppose the following constructor:

```
class Needed
{
public: 
    Needed () {}
    Needed (const char *name) {}
};


class Dummy
{
public:
    Dummy (): needed ( "Jimmy" ) {}

private:
    Needed needed;
};
```

So, did I initialized `needed` twice here?

Comment: No. Why did you think you did?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No you initialized it only once in the **[Member Initializer List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor/8523361#8523361)**.

Comment: The list itself doesn't "initialize" the member object, though. The object is *always* initialized. The list just says *how* to initialize it.

Answer (score 1):

No, it only gets initialized once for each `Dummy` instance. You just supplied the arguments for its initialization (and selected which constructor to use).